# How to print drop down menu items as a list in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a drop down menu which has a few options and i can print the total price but i want to add something else like the name of selected option which is written in HERE part. For example if the value of my option is 20 i want to print it like HERE -> 20 but could not make it happen.

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/chr1sw0w/pen/xxggKXV) of my code:

```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function calculatePrice(){

    //Get selected data  
    var elt = document.getElementById("foodItem");
    var food = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

    elt = document.getElementById("drinkItem");
    var drink = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

    elt = document.getElementById("desertItem");
    var desert = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
    
    elt = document.getElementById("tipItem");
    var tip = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

    //convert data to integers
    food = parseInt(food);
    drink = parseInt(drink);
    desert = parseInt(desert);
    tip = parseInt(tip);

    //calculate total value  
    var total = food+drink+desert+tip; 

    //print value to  PicExtPrice 
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").value=total;

}
  </script>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center>
<FORM Name="myform">
    <SELECT NAME="foodItem" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="foodItem">
       <OPTION value="0">Select your food</OPTION>
       <OPTION value="35">Anthic Steak </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="20">Anthic Lasagna </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="15">Anthic Pasta </OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT NAME="drinkItem" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="drinkItem">
       <OPTION value="0">Select your drink</OPTION>
       <OPTION value="5">Coke </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="10">Spritz </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="15">Beer </OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT NAME="desertItem" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="desertItem">
       <OPTION value="0">Select your desert</OPTION>
       <OPTION value="15">Baklava </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="20">Sütlaç </OPTION>
       <OPTION value="25">Sufle </OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT NAME="tipItem" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="tipItem">
        <OPTION value="0">Would you like to tip?</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="0">No,thanks. </OPTION>
        <OPTION value="10">10TL </OPTION>
        <OPTION value="15">15TL </OPTION>
        <OPTION value="20">20TL </OPTION>

     </SELECT>
</FORM>

<br><br>The amount you have to pay:<br><br><INPUT type="text" id="totalPrice" Size=8>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

I will create a larger textbox and i want to list them as;
Anthic Steak -> 20TL
Drink -> 10TL
Desert -> 5TL
Tip -> 10TL
Total Price -> 45TL

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Try this https://codepen.io/chr1sw0w/pen/xxggKXV

Comment: @CodingWithRoyal This is the same code with i share, can you check again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty neat and your existing function `calculatePrice` can make use of an extra snippet to just create a billing summary as you explained. You are currently using the variable `elt` to get all the elements by Id, which can be kept unique so that you can later use them to fetch the **text** value of dropdown, and create a summary. Finally you can add this summary to an empty tag(say div) using its id. Here's an alteration to your `JavaScript`:

```js
    function calculatePrice() {

        //Get selected data  
        var foodElt = document.getElementById("foodItem");
        var food = foodElt.options[foodElt.selectedIndex].value;

        var drinkElt = document.getElementById("drinkItem");
        var drink = drinkElt.options[drinkElt.selectedIndex].value;

        desertElt = document.getElementById("desertItem");
        var desert = desertElt.options[desertElt.selectedIndex].value;

        tipElt = document.getElementById("tipItem");
        var tip = tipElt.options[tipElt.selectedIndex].value;

        //convert data to integers
        food = parseInt(food);
        drink = parseInt(drink);
        desert = parseInt(desert);
        tip = parseInt(tip);

        //calculate total value  
        var total = food + drink + desert + tip;

        //print value to  PicExtPrice 
        document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = total;

        var summary = '';
        if (food > 0) {
            summary += foodElt.options[foodElt.selectedIndex].text + ' : ' + food + '\n';
        }
        if (drink > 0) {
            summary += drinkElt.options[drinkElt.selectedIndex].text + ' : ' + drink + '\n';
        }
        if (desert > 0) {
            summary += desertElt.options[desertElt.selectedIndex].text + ' : ' + desert + '\n';
        }
        if (tip > 0) {
            summary += 'Tip' + ' : ' + tip + '\n';
        }

        document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = summary;

    }
```

Here's an addition to HTML:

```html
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Note: You can simply make use of the same variable `elt`, but you will have to manage summary calculation inline ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really understand the logic. But still don't understand how to print the summary. I was using The amount you have to pay:<br><br><INPUT type="text" id="totalPrice" Size=8> for price part but when i try to use it for summary i couldn't get an output.

Comment: You only need summary and not total price? Just replace the html part that you have sent above with this: <div id="summary"></div>

Comment: Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/deepaksingh25/pen/zYNNxKJ